# GeoViews: Categorical legend for GeoDataFrames with matplotlib backend

Tags: geoviews

#### Installed packages

geoviews 1.9.1., matplotlib 3.4.2.

#### What I'm trying to do

For the `Bokeh` backend adding a categorical legend via `GeoViews` is done through proxy artists, as describe in the [Katrina track example](https://geoviews.org/gallery/bokeh/katrina_track.html), and I managed to get this to work, but how does this work for the `Matplotlib` backend? The corresponding [mpl example for the Katrina track case](https://geoviews.org/gallery/matplotlib/katrina_track.html#matplotlib-gallery-katrina-track), notably does not include a legend. The other `mpl` examples with legends all use colorbars.

The `HoloViews` [legend example](http://holoviews.org/gallery/demos/matplotlib/legend_example.html) suggests that this is done automatically, so I figured the same would apply for `GeoViews` but when trying to repro the example with GeoDataFrames as inputs to `gv.Polygons`, no legend appears.

#### Reproducible example

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import geoviews as gv
from geoviews import opts

gv.extension('matplotlib')

d1 = {'use': {0: 'Residential', 1: 'Residential'},
'geometry': {0: 'POLYGON ((13.80961103741604 51.04076975651729, 13.80965521888065 51.04079016168103, 13.80963851766593 51.04080454197601, 13.80959433642561 51.04078412781548, 13.80961103741604 51.04076975651729))',
1: 'POLYGON ((13.80977831740752 51.04313480566009, 13.80987122363639 51.04306085051974, 13.8099989591537 51.04312462457182, 13.80995486494384 51.04315973323087, 13.8099651184249 51.04316486464228, 13.80991634926543 51.04320371166482, 13.80977831740752 51.04313480566009))'}}

gdf1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(d1), geometry=gpd.GeoSeries.from_wkt(pd.DataFrame(d1)['geometry']), crs="EPSG:4326")

d2 = {'geometry': {1: 'POLYGON ((13.80894179055831 51.04544128170094, 13.80952887156242 51.0450399782091, 13.80954152432486 51.04504668985658, 13.80896834397535 51.04545611172818, 13.80894179055831 51.04544128170094))'}}

gdf2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(d2), geometry=gpd.GeoSeries.from_wkt(pd.DataFrame(d2)['geometry']), crs="EPSG:4326")


feature1 = gv.Polygons(gdf1, group="group1", label='label1')
feature2 = gv.Polygons(gdf2, group="group2", label='label2')

layout = feature1.opts(color='red') * feature2.opts(color='lightgrey')

layout.opts(
            opts.Polygons('group1', cmap=['red'], edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.5, xaxis=None, yaxis=None),
            opts.Polygons('group2', cmap=['lightblue'], edgecolor='blue', linewidth=0.5),
            opts.Overlay(fig_size=500)
        )
        
gv.output(layout)
```

Any pointers would be appreciated (also, if possible, on an earlier [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68318769/geoviews-applying-matplotlib-styling-parameters-to-polygons-elements) of mine from a couple of weeks ago).

Answer (score 0):

It is likely due to this known issue still outstanding: https://github.com/holoviz/geoviews/issues/450

Both your example and the one in the linked issue leads to this error:

```
File ~\.conda\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\legend_handler.py:768, in HandlerTuple.create_artists(self, legend, orig_handle, xdescent, ydescent, width, height, fontsize, trans)
    766 for handle1 in orig_handle:
    767     handler = legend.get_legend_handler(handler_map, handle1)
--> 768     _a_list = handler.create_artists(
    769         legend, handle1,
    770         next(xds_cycle), ydescent, width, height, fontsize, trans)
    771     a_list.extend(_a_list)
    773 return a_list

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create_artists'
```