# GeoViews: adding a tile basemap using matplotlib backend

Tags: python, geoviews

Using the `matplotlib` backend, is it possible to add a tile basemap such as OSM to a `GeoViews`plot, e.g. by somehow calling `contextily`? Using the `Bokeh` backend, this is done via `gv.tile_sources` and then adding it to an overlay but is there a similar function for the `mpl` backend?

#### Post-answer edit

Adding a reproducible example assuming one is switching between backends, and using neighbourhood-level polygon gdfs in EPSG:4326.

What made me initially think adding a basemap was not possible was (1) not defining the WMTS zoom level (causing undecipherable pixelated text to be plotted instead of features), and, after reading James' answer, (2) adding the tiles layer to the layout last, not first, which caused tiles to cover the polygons layers (not an issue on the bokeh backend, but with matplotlib apparently it does matter).

```
import geoviews as gv
from geoviews import opts
from cartopy import crs as ccrs

gv.extension('bokeh', 'matplotlib')

tiles = gv.tile_sources.OSM()

layout = tiles * gv.Polygons(gdf1, group="group1") * gv.Polygons(gdf2, group="group2")

layout.opts(
            opts.Polygons('group1', cmap=['red'], backend="matplotlib"),
            opts.Polygons('group2', cmap=['lightgrey'], backend="matplotlib"),
            opts.Overlay(backend='matplotlib'),
            opts.WMTS(zoom=13, backend='matplotlib'),
            projection=ccrs.Mercator()
        )
        
gv.output(layout, size=500, fig='svg', backend='matplotlib')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, [same as for Bokeh](https://geoviews.org/gallery/matplotlib/tile_sources.html):

```
import geoviews as gv
from geoviews import opts, tile_sources as gvts
gv.extension('matplotlib')

opts.defaults(
    opts.Layout(sublabel_format='', vspace=0.1, hspace=0.1, fig_size=200),
    opts.WMTS(zoom=0))

(gvts.Wikipedia + gvts.StamenToner + gvts.EsriNatGeo + gvts.EsriImagery +
 gvts.EsriUSATopo + gvts.EsriTerrain + gvts.EsriReference + gvts.StamenTerrain).cols(4)
```

[image]

Comment: Cheers, James! That was my bad. I added a reproducible example after I figured out why it didn't work for me initially, thanks to you pointing me to the example (which I somehow missed). If you have some time, would you mind having a look at two related gv+mpl questions of mine from [last week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68559470/geoviews-categorical-legend-for-geodataframes-with-matplotlib-backend) and [a month ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68318769/geoviews-applying-matplotlib-styling-parameters-to-polygons-elements), respectively? Much appreciated!